# C# - Unable to read an HKLM Registry Key (Object reference not set to an instance of an object)

Tags: c#, registry

I've found similar posts and I've tried various combinations of examples but cannot get this working. I have the following registry setup and I'm trying to get the CONNECTWISEID value and set it to a string variable:

[image: Registry]

Here is the code (Note I'm opening the key in read only):

```
try
        {
            RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\CentraStage", false);
            string connectwiseId = (string)key.GetValue("CONNECTWISEID");
            key.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(connectwiseId, "Reg Key Value", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

An error is always caught and I get the following error:

[[image: Error[2]]

The registry keys are not in the WOW6432Node branch either. I've also tried this code with no success:

```
string connectwiseId = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\CentraStage", "CONNECTWISEID", null);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Permissions for the user trying to open the key?

Comment: @steve - Don't belive so. Checked the permissions and also tried running as Administrator - same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSubKey appears to return the next key down the chain, so the following is probably what you need:

```
try
    {
        // Opens the software key
        RegistryKey softwareKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE", false);
        // Opens the CetraStage key
        RegistryKey key = softwareKey.OpenSubKey("CentraStage", false);
        string connectwiseId = (string)key.GetValue("CONNECTWISEID");
        key.Close();
        MessageBox.Show(connectwiseId, "Reg Key Value", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
```

MSDN link for OpenSubKey: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.opensubkey?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. After trying this, I still end up with the same error. :(